# PowerApps Date Format Issue

Tags: powerapps

Why is the date exporting out as a format other than what I set it to???

[image: Error Code]

[image: Date Selected]

[image: Format]

Answer (score 0):

The format property in the date picker control only determines how the date is displayed (and possibly parsed, if editable) in the control itself. If you need to pass a date to a flow (or a custom connector) as a string with a specific format, you need to use the [Text function](https://learn.microsoft.com/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-text) to convert it to the format you want, something along the lines of

```
InsertFlow.Run(...Text(DatePicker1.SelectedDate, "yyyy-mm-dd")...)
```